# Tomcat shutdown: The process cannot access the file

Tags: java, tomcat

people.

Can somebody please help with this...

After Tomcat started by running `startup.bat` - need to stop it but get:

```
c:\Opt\tomcat_8080\bin>shutdown.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   c:\Opt\tomcat_8080
Using CATALINA_HOME:   c:\Opt\tomcat_8080
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: c:\Opt\tomcat_8080\temp
Using JRE_HOME:        C:\Opt\jdk1.6.0_32x64\jre
Using CLASSPATH:       c:\Opt\tomcat_8080\bin\bootstrap.jar
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I can't use `taskkill` - because there is few `java.exe` processes - so I can't get `PID` of just `Tomcat`... Just kill it manually from `Process Explorer` - but need to do it automatically, from script which will be called from `TeamCity` server.

OS - `Windows 7`, `Tomcat 5.5.36`.

Comment: Try to kill all processes in the group.

Comment: You can use `jps -v` to get the correct PID.

Comment: `jps -v` looks good, but.... It's not Linux system with it perfect "cut, grep" etc tools... So - how in Windows I can get only PID and call taskkil with it?

Comment: You can install grep in windows with http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Solved by:

1) Added line to `/bin/startup.bat`:

```
set title="Tomcat"
```

So now I have description of **Java** process in `tasklist` (needed because there is few **Java** process and need to kill only **Tomcat**).

2) First command - select process with `Title` **Tomcat** and write it in to file:

```
>tasklist /v /FI "IMAGENAME eq java.exe" | findstr /i "Tomcat" > tomcatpid.txt
```

3) Second command - select `TOKEN 2` (which is `PID` of previously selected process) and run `taskkill`:

```
>for /F "TOKENS=2" %a in ('type tomcatpid.txt') do (taskkill /PID %a)

>(taskkill /PID 3360 )
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process with PID 3360.
```

Hope - this will help somebody :-)

I sure there more simple solution - but writing scripts for **Windows** are mnot my favorite occupation...